# iOS hover effect on tap and not on click

Tags: ios, css, hover

I always thought the hover effect on iOS devices is only visible on a complete "click" (or "touch") but then i found this page:

http://www.theverge.com/2013/2/19/4004250/sunrise-for-iphone-calendar-app-for-a-post-google-world

Here the hover effect is visible when I just tap on an element (without delay) and leaves when i leave my finger - no complete click is necessary.

I don't get it. What is the trick?

Comment: what do you mean with complete click? there are only touch downs and touch ups on a touch device. can`t see any trick in the video.

Comment: i mean the page itself. not the article. normally i see the hover effects of links when i take a complete click (press the finger on a link, then leave and THEN i see the hover effect). but on this page i see the hover effect instantly when i touch on a link. and the hover effect leaves if i leave my finger. there must be a difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got it!

just add `ontouchstart=""` to your body tag:

```
<body ontouchstart=""> ...
```

Comment: FLAWLESS! Thanks. Just tested on an iPhone 6 Plus w/ iOS 8.4.1

Comment: WHAT! This is both fantastic and insane. Can anyone enlighten as to why this works?